# How to set installer variables to integer action fields?

Tags: java, install4j

Is it possible to set installer variables to integer field in custom actions? Maybe if we need to define some values for connection timeouts at installation runtime and set this to customized action as integer values.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 6.1 it is not possible for the user to enter installer variables for numeric fields. This is planned for a future version.

Comment: Okay, maybe the question was unclear. I want to set installer variables inside the IDE to action fields which are define as int-values. In the IDE I see integer formatted input fields without the possibility to select installer vairables.

Comment: "I see integer formatted input fields" Are you talking about the "Text field with integer format" form component? Can you post a screenshot of where you want to select a variable?

Comment: You are right. I meant the text input field in the IDE. I added the screenshot. For the marked field I would like to set `${installer:timeout.default}` or something else.

Comment: OK, now I understand, I've edited the answer. It's something we've been thinking about for quite some time.